# Instantiating a subclass works in Swift playgrounds, but using the class itself does not

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, audiokit

I have made an update to AudioKit's code, and now the playgrounds (on the develop branch) don't all work, and in researching I've found a strange case where

```
var oscillator = AKOscillator()
```

generates a crash, but simply using a trivial subclass of that class:

```
class AKSubclassOfOscillator: AKOscillator {}
var oscillator = AKSubclassOfOscillator()
```

works perfectly well. Can someone shed some light on how this could possibly be happening? This Swift Playground is running/crashing in Xcode 10.  Similar code in an app does not crash, only inside the playground.

Here's the log

```
Playground execution failed:

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010c8b2d2f libswiftCore.dylib`swift_getObjectType + 47
    frame #1: 0x000000010c86a855 libswiftCore.dylib`findDynamicValueAndType(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool&, bool, bool) + 245
    frame #2: 0x000000010c86efa7 libswiftCore.dylib`_dynamicCastToExistential(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetExistentialTypeMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags) + 135
    frame #3: 0x000000010cbda1b7 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol258$$PlaygroundLogger + 599
    frame #4: 0x000000010cbdc8e6 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol269$$PlaygroundLogger + 262
    frame #5: 0x000000010cbdf02c PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol298$$PlaygroundLogger + 76
    frame #6: 0x000000010cbdf6f9 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol333$$PlaygroundLogger + 9
    frame #7: 0x000000010cbdf07f PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol300$$PlaygroundLogger + 31
    frame #8: 0x000000010cbdf609 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol318$$PlaygroundLogger + 9
    frame #9: 0x000000010c58a50f libswiftCore.dylib`(extension in Swift):Swift.Collection.map<A>((A.Element) throws -> A1) throws -> Swift.Array<A1> + 527
    frame #10: 0x000000010c6d600e libswiftCore.dylib`protocol witness for Swift.Sequence.map<A>((A.Element) throws -> A1) throws -> Swift.Array<A1> in conformance Swift.LazyMapCollection<A, B> : Swift.Sequence in Swift + 78
    frame #11: 0x000000010c783347 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift._RandomAccessCollectionBox._map<A>((A.Element) throws -> A1) throws -> Swift.Array<A1> + 135
    frame #12: 0x000000010cbdcbaf PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol270$$PlaygroundLogger + 383
    frame #13: 0x000000010cbde62d PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol284$$PlaygroundLogger + 1357
    frame #14: 0x000000010cbdcd1a PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol270$$PlaygroundLogger + 746
    frame #15: 0x000000010cbde62d PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol284$$PlaygroundLogger + 1357
    frame #16: 0x000000010cbdbc84 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol258$$PlaygroundLogger + 7460
    frame #17: 0x000000010cbd5752 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol179$$PlaygroundLogger + 114
    frame #18: 0x000000010cbd78e8 PlaygroundLogger`playground_log_hidden + 264
    frame #19: 0x000000010d1e9427 $__lldb_expr10`main at Oscillator.xcplaygroundpage:16
    frame #20: 0x0000000108f881a0 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx
    frame #21: 0x00007fff3643bf8c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #22: 0x00007fff3643be5f CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 311
    frame #23: 0x00007fff3649d53d CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 56
    frame #24: 0x00007fff5f53cbf5 ViewBridge`__68-[NSVB_ViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:]_block_invoke_2 + 46
    frame #25: 0x00007fff5f501ec6 ViewBridge`-[NSViewServiceMarshal withHostWindowFrameAnimationInProgress:perform:] + 53
    frame #26: 0x00007fff5f53cbbe ViewBridge`__68-[NSVB_ViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:]_block_invoke + 113
    frame #27: 0x00007fff33a19731 AppKit`+[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:] + 55
    frame #28: 0x00007fff33a196e7 AppKit`+[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:completionHandler:] + 82
    frame #29: 0x00007fff5f55f154 ViewBridge`runAnimationGroup + 295
    frame #30: 0x00007fff5f53c695 ViewBridge`+[NSVB_View _animateWithAttributes:animations:completion:] + 490
    frame #31: 0x00007fff5f53cb28 ViewBridge`-[NSVB_ViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 206
    frame #32: 0x00007fff3648580e CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 780
    frame #33: 0x00007fff36485478 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 120
    frame #34: 0x00007fff3643bf8c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #35: 0x00007fff3643be5f CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 311
    frame #36: 0x00007fff3649d53d CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 56
    frame #37: 0x00007fff5f504973 ViewBridge`-[NSVB_QueueingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 324
    frame #38: 0x00007fff3648580e CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 780
    frame #39: 0x00007fff36485478 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 120
    frame #40: 0x00007fff3643bf8c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #41: 0x00007fff3643be5f CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 311
    frame #42: 0x00007fff3649d53d CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 56
    frame #43: 0x00007fff3648580e CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 780
    frame #44: 0x00007fff36485478 CoreFoundation`__forwarding_prep_0___ + 120
    frame #45: 0x00007fff3643bf8c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #46: 0x00007fff3643be5f CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 311
    frame #47: 0x00007fff5f4d16cd ViewBridge`__deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke + 237
    frame #48: 0x00007fff5f4c6af3 ViewBridge`__wrapBlockWithVoucher_block_invoke + 37
    frame #49: 0x00007fff5f4c68a4 ViewBridge`__deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 + 553
    frame #50: 0x00007fff36469ca7 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #51: 0x00007fff3642cced CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 395
    frame #52: 0x00007fff3642c3eb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1204
    frame #53: 0x00007fff3642bce4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 463
    frame #54: 0x00007fff356c5895 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 293
    frame #55: 0x00007fff356c55cb HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 618
    frame #56: 0x00007fff356c5348 HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    frame #57: 0x00007fff3398295b AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 997
    frame #58: 0x00007fff339816fa AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1362
    frame #59: 0x00007fff5f4cf226 ViewBridge`-[NSViewServiceApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 92
    frame #60: 0x00007fff3397b75d AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 699
    frame #61: 0x00007fff3396ae97 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 780
    frame #62: 0x00007fff636fbf1f libxpc.dylib`_xpc_objc_main + 612
    frame #63: 0x00007fff636fb9e5 libxpc.dylib`xpc_main + 433
    frame #64: 0x00007fff5f4c0a76 ViewBridge`-[NSXPCSharedListener resume] + 16
    frame #65: 0x00007fff5f4c9a03 ViewBridge`NSViewServiceApplicationMain + 2877
    frame #66: 0x0000000108f881ca com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx`main + 42
    frame #67: 0x00007fff634c5085 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: I've solved the problem through other means, so its not a pressing matter anymore, but I'm still so perplexed as to how a simple subleasing could have fixed anything. We may never know.

Comment: As a place to hunt, note that the part that's failing is in the logger (which makes it specific to Playgrounds). So maybe something related to `description` or one of the related methods?

Answer (score 2):

This code relies on `_Self`, which I don't believe is documented behavior, and may not be reliable in all usages. I believe everywhere this code uses `_Self`, it means to use `type(of: self)`.

Comment: Sorry about that Aurelius; I knew that…just didn't look closely enough. Thanks matt.

Comment: Interesting.  Some classes that rely on _Self do still work though, but this at least gives me something to consider.

Comment: Removing _Self is smart, and I'm doing it for all classes, so thanks for pointing that out, but it doesn't seem to be the cause of this problem. I'll update your answer, but not accept it just yet.

Comment: Actually _Self didn't seem to be the root cause here.